# Несколько нод с Wordpress и WP Super Cache: копировать ли кэш?

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на WP построен звездой: один Центр с админкой и мастером MySQL, и пул из нескольких Нод со slave'ами MySQL, без админки - только на выдачу страниц.

На нодах стоит WP Super Cache, который отрендеренные страницы сохраняет в статичных html файлах. Работает в режиме "запросили страницу — создал её кэш, если ещё не". Т.е. набор закэшированных страниц на разных нодах разный.

Вопрос: стоит ли на файловом уровне синхронизировать эти кэшированные страницы между нодами, или пусть каждая нода бултыхается самостоятельно?

Ещё возможный сценарий - принудительно генерить кэш всех страниц сайта на Центровом сервере, и оттуда сливать на все Ноды. Тогда неочевидно, зачем они вообще нужны. Только если все посетители вздумают одновременно поиском по сайту заняться интенсивно 6 )

Upd. Выяснился еще один момент: ведь при обновлении поста, на Ноды уходит пуш MySQL, но никакого события WP не запускается, и кэш для обновлённо записи не перестраивается. Пока "лечу" это коротким временем жизни кэша.